# Azure HDinsight Kafka and configure kafka for ip advertising

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-hdinsight

I am looking for some info on the Azure HDInsight Kafka and making the kafka to advertise IP addresses instead of FQDNs.
When we create a HDInsight Kafka, by default it creates azure provided internal FQDNs and these FQDNs are able to resolve with in the vnets. Across vnets, we can't resolve these FQDNs. Even if we want to resolve, then we have to go with custom DNS as per Azure documentation. As an alternate to this, we can go with kafka to advertise its IP addresses rather FQDNs. This can be achieved using Ambari cluster management tool/dashboard and where we have to add a few lines of text in the kafka config(kafka-env template)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-connect-vpn-gateway#configure-kafka-for-ip-advertising

As part of above link, we have to go and add below lines of text on the "kafka-env template" to make IP advertisement.

```
#Configure Kafka to advertise IP addresses instead of FQDN
IP_ADDRESS=$(hostname -i)
echo advertised.listeners=$IP_ADDRESS
sed -i.bak -e '/advertised/{/advertised@/!d;}' /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/conf/server.properties
echo "advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://$IP_ADDRESS:9092" >> /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/conf/server.properties
```

But this is a manual step that we have to do by going through the Ambari dashboard.

But We are looking for completely automate adding the above text (no manual intervention of going to amabari dashboard and add the same above text) using some REST API mechanism or some other way.

From Azure doc and many other related docs, I didn't find any way, which will explain the same either by REST API or any other way.

As anyone done this automating or anyone aware of how to automate configuration management on this ambari dashboard for IP advertising for Kafka and other config management either by REST or any other way?

In general we are looking for automating IP advertisement on HD insight Kafka instead manually going into the Ambari dashboard and add the above text manually.

Answer (score 1):

Ambari exposes rest endpoints which can be used to modify the configuration for components like Kafka. You can use rest clients to automate it.

Please refer: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Modify+configurations

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Service+Config+Versions+API+usage